# Foreground(/Background) Service Or Geofencing API

Tags: android, location, polling, android-intentservice, android-workmanager

I am working on an android app that has to update location every 10 seconds. Means I have to do polling for every 10 seconds when user wanted to do.

- Which one is better to use Service or Geofencing API.
- Which will be better for reducing battery draining.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot poll every `10`s unless you use a foreground `Service`. O enforces background limits, and doze so unless you are in the foreground, this is a bad idea. You might want to reconsider if that's the best approach at solving your problem and consider alternative APIs like geo-fencing etc.